# Ionic Appflow .gitignore for existing project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gitignore, ionic-appflow

We are trying to migrate an existing project from Phonegap to Ionic Appflow. This is a pure Javascript project without any Angular/React. We are using Ionic to take advantage of its build, push to app stores and liveupdate features. We are not sure which folders to exclude from github using .gitignore.

The [migration guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/cookbook/phonegap-build-migration) only mentions the node_modules folder, but what about other folders such as: /platforms /plugins etc.? It looks like Appflow only needs the following:

/www

/Resources

config.xml

package.json

ionic.config.json

and everything else should be excluded from the github repository?